# compile static binary while using <sqlite3>?

Tags: c++, sqlite, api, compilation, static

Is it possible to compile a program that uses sqlite3.h (-lsqlite3) into a static binary?

here is what happens when I try:

```
 g++ -m64 -std=c++17 -static Database.cpp -o test.app `pkg-config --static --cflags --libs sqlite3`

/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.a(sqlite3.o): in function `unixDlOpen':
(.text+0x8d49): warning: Using 'dlopen' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking`
```

Linux x86_64

Comment: Did you check if your Linux distribution provides static libraries for sqlite3? If it doesn't, if you don't have `sqlite3.a`, there's nothing that you can do.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik it does, and the error is coming from libsqlite3.a

Comment: You're better off including the sqlite source directly in your project instead of using a system library version (and compile it with the option to disable dynamic loading of extension modules)

Comment: @Shawn I'll try that, thanks.